# Android: DialogFragment and universal xml

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to take control of the database in android with Dialog Fragments. I mean, for example to add a new record I will click a button and pop-up fragment appears asking me for the specific fields. I click ok which fires the method in my hosting activity. That part works.

However, I also want to have other operations like delete, update, search  record ect.

Is there a way to have a universal code for fragment but then assign different xml according to different database operations?
I am looking for the most efficient way around my problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can inflate different views on your Fragment...

```
public class MyClass extends Fragment {
String xmlToLoad;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstances);
    Bundle data = getArguments();
    xmlToLoad = data.getString("what you set in your fragments pager");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(xmlToLoad.equals("whatever")) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.thisXML, container,false);
    }
}
}
```